# Access: Compare array variable with string

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to compare a value within an array with a text string.
The array is generated by splitting a record containing a string.
Please see the pseudo-code below.

```
Dim fish As Variant
fish = Split(myRS![Field2], " ")
    If fish(Array reference hear?) = "whatever string" Then
            'whatever else in hear  
    End If
```

I think I am having the following issues – referencing the correct part of the array and then converting the value to a string

Answer (score 1):

If you need only to determine whether one or more of the array elements matches your search text, consider the `Filter` function.

In this example, `Filter` returns *FishMatched* as a one-dimensional array which contains the matching members from the first array (*AllFish*):

```vb
Dim AllFish As Variant
Dim FishMatched As Variant
AllFish = Split(myRS![Field2], " ")
FishMatched = Filter(AllFish, "whatever string")
If UBound(FishMatched) >= 0 Then
    Debug.Print UBound(FishMatched) + 1; " match(es) found."
Else
    Debug.Print "No match found."
End If
```

This approach may be suitable if you only need to know whether your search text is present among the members of *AllFish*.  However, since it creates a new array containing the matches, it can not tell you the index of the *AllFish* member which matched.

Answer (score 0):

You need a for loop to cycle the strings inside your array. `LBound` and `UBound` are needed to get the range of your array. You can check inside the loop if `theStringYouAreLookingFor` Is equal to the value of current array position `i`

```
Dim fish As Variant
Dim theStringYouAreLookingFor as String
theStringYouAreLookingFor = "here is what I'm looking for"
fish = Split(myRS![Field2], " ")

For i = LBound(fish) To UBound(fish)
    If theStringYouAreLookingFor = fish(i) then
        Debug.Print "Found it at " & cstr(i + 1) & " position in array"
        Exit for
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Guys! Genius code both. I have uses for both code pieces- many thanks for your awesome help - digital fist pump and a merry xmas